# Only some badges showing available on Stack Overflow profile page

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page, badges

I recently noticed that on the 'select your next badge' SO popup, only very few badges are available in the dialog.
I know quite a few SO users have many, many badges, definitely more than what shows in the dialog.
Is this a glitch, on propose (I haven't earned enough reputation yet, you need more to get those badges), or something else.